# Nodejs : Promise chain terminates after a certain limit without throwing any errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to do a simple operation in nodejs using promises. I have an array, which contains objects. These objects in turn contain query parameters for a url that I want to hit with a GET request. I want the get requests to be sequential, as the number of requests is around 6000. I searched around the internet and stumbled onto this medium article which shows how to run promises sequentially.
[Medium article link](https://medium.com/developer-rants/running-promises-in-a-loop-sequentially-one-by-one-bd803181b283)

Following the approach, I wrote the following snippet -

```js
let itr = set[Symbol.iterator]();//set which contains the objects to be pushed to the function 
                                //that makes the GET request
let runNext = ()=>{
    fetchLinks(itr.next().value).then( x =>{ //fetchLinks returns a new Promise which wraps the 
                                            //GET request. on successful response, I resolve(1)
        runNext();
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log("storing");
        translateMapAndStore();//fetchLinks returns a reject when an undefined object is detected.
                  //a global object is storing the response data which is then written to a file.
    });
}
runNext();//initiate the recursive promise chain
```

The error that I face right now is that the process terminates after fetching exactly 11 times. I don't know the reason behind this. No errors are thrown and the process exits gracefully. Is there something that I have missed here?

Comment: Additional info about runtime env - MacOS Big Sur 11.5.1 + node version 15.14.0

Comment: It feels wrong that you use `Symbol.iterator` for async operation.  You may need [Symbol.asyncIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) instead. Also what is the purpose to use iterator? why not just use a simple for loop with `await` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just like below?

```js
const urls = ["url0", "url1", "url2"];

(async function run() {
  for (const url of urls) {
    try {
      await fetchLinks(url);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("storing");
      translateMapAndStore();
    }
  }
})();
```